# Can screen reader like JAWS read jGrowl message?

Tags: jquery, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, jgrowl

In my web app, whenever any error occurs, that error message is being displayed through jGrowl box:

```
$.jGrowl("This is an error message.");
```

Also I use the jGrowl box for showing normal messages/notifications. I am making my app accessibility friendly. I am using JAWS as screen reader. When a jGrowl message pops up, JAWS is not reading that message.

How do I make JAWS read that message? Any workaround?

Or is there any jQuery method through which I'd know that a jGrowl message is being displayed so that I can set focus or something so that the screen reader reads that message and notify the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know jGrowl, and you have offered no URL, but this may be a case for [ARIA live regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions).

Comment: jGrowl has not been updated to be aria-friendly. I would love to merge a PR if you're interested in contributing though!

Comment: @stanlemon I don't have much experience with ARIA, but sure! I'd love to contribute something and learn on the same side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:

I did a workaround to make the jGrowl messages/notifications readable by screen readers like JAWS. For that I modified the **jquery.jgrowl.min.js** file a bit.

First find below line in the jquery.jgrowl.min.js file(which by the way plays an important role to render the jGrowl popup):

```
var t=e("<div />").addClass("jGrowl-notification "+n.themeState+" ui-corner-all"+(void 0!=n.group&&""!=n.group?" "+n.group:""))
```

And now add a '**role**' attribute assign '**alert**' as a value in that div. You can also add an **ARIA label** which will have the message to be read by screen reader.

So after changes, it looks something like this:

```
var t=e("<div role='alert' />").attr('aria-label',t.message).addClass("jGrowl-notification "+n.themeState+" ui-corner-all"+(void 0!=n.group&&""!=n.group?" "+n.group:""))
```

Hope this is helpful. It worked for me :)